# which is correct, "John promoted to corporal" or "John was promoted to corporal"

Tags: verbs

Does the word "was" imply John promoted himself or it was done by others?

Comment: John can't promote himself to corporal.  The promotion was done by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

"John was promoted" is correct and does *not* imply that he promoted himself.

"John promoted" would only be used if it was necessary to use as few words as possible, for example in a newspaper headline.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant that I thought "John promoted" implied an action he caused, and "John was promoted" was an action caused by others, or done to him. Thank you.